# Initializing a static const char* array

Tags: static, char, constants

here is my question I have this in my .h file

```
static const char *Title[];
```

How do I initialize the array in my .C file the array to lets say "first", "second", "third"

Comment: Are you sure you really want this in a header file?

Comment: Well if it's in a class it would make sense wouldn't it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`static const char* Title[] = { "first", "second", "third" };`

Check out this little blurb on [initialization](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html).  Why do you want to do it in separate files?  You'll have to do externs.

```
// in .h
extern const char* Title[];

// in .c
const char* Title[] = { "first", "second" };
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's C++ you could wrap this array about a class and create a static instance of it.