# error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const char'

Tags: c

I am getting this error --
error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const char'

my code is in c and the error is in my .h file.. this is what the code looks like that is getting the errors

```
const char *c2ptr[37]={ 0, 4, 8,11,14,16,18,20,23,25,
           27,29, 3,31,34,37, 3, 3,39,44,
           48,51,54,57,60, 3,62,65, 3,68,
           72,75, 3,77,79,81,84},
    ch,inif,*fname,
    comf[4]={ 7, 8, 9,13};
```

and so... the errors all pop up on the ch,inif,*fname... does it have to do with the fact that they are not arrays? as far as i know this is legal.

Comment: oh and it also says to add an explicit initializer to initialize 'ch' and 'inif' etc.. what is this asking me to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code declares four variables:

- An array `c2ptr` of items of type `const char*`
- A constant `ch` of type `char`
- A constant `inif` of type `char`
- A variable `fname` of type `const char*`
- A constant array `comf` of items of type `char`

First of all, `c2ptr` is an array of `const char*` (strings), but your code initializes it to a list of `int`, `{ 0, 4, 8, 11, ... }`.

Secondly, your variables `ch` and `inif` are constants, but haven't been assigned a value to them. Since a constant variable can't be changed, you must assign a value to them in the declaration. (This is probably what's giving you errors.)

Answer (score 1):

You declared the array for `const char *` pointers, and initialized it with `int`, maybe you meant

```
static const char *c2ptr[37] = {
        "0",  "4",  "8", "11", "14", "16", "18", "20", "23", "25",
       "27", "29",  "3", "31", "34", "37",  "3",  "3", "39", "44",
       "48", "51", "54", "57", "60",  "3", "62", "65",  "3", "68",
       "72", "75",  "3", "77", "79", "81", "84"
   };
```

Comment: I don't think that's his primary issue.  He's trying to statically initialize an array in the header file and that's what the compiler is telling him.

Comment: I just tried it.  I stuck "const char *tmp1 = {"hello"};" into a header file.  I get "multiple definition of  tmp1" errors when linking.  Also, this seems to back me up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814804/initializing-a-static-const-char-array

Comment: @rost0031 You *can* initialize an array in a header file, but you often shouldn't because you'll run into those errors if you include the header in multiple source files. Since header files are just inserted directly into the source file before compilation, the effect of initializing an array in a header file and a source file would be just the same. (And in this case, that's not what the compiler is complaining about; it's complaining about constant variables without a default value, namely `ch` and `inif`.)