# Is there any difference between default built-in constructor and non-parameterized user-created default constructor?

Tags: c++, object, oop, constructor, default-constructor

Why does this work:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class student{
    int rollNumber;
    int age;

public :
    student(){

    }
};

int main(){
    student const s;
}
```

But this does not work?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class student{

    int rollNumber;
    int age;

};

int main(){
    student const s;
}
```

In both cases, there is a default constructor.

The top one has a user-defined default constructor, and the bottom one has the built-in default constructor.

Is there any difference between the default built-in constructor and a non-parameterized user-created default constructor?

In the second one, will the built-in default constructor be the same as the user-defined non-parameterized constructor?

Is there anyone who knows why this is happening?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338674/error-default-initialization-of-an-object-of-const-type-const-char) is about `const char` instead of `const student` but the same reasoning applies. If you provide your own default constructor, the compiler will assume that you know what you're doing and that `student const s;` with no arguments is meaningful. But it knows that the default-generated default constructor leaves `rollNumber` and `age` uninitialized and that therefore `s` is presumptively invalid.

Comment: Another difference between the default-generated default constructor and `student() { }` is that the former is `noexcept` and the latter is not.

Comment: [Default constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) about 4 pages of explanation.

Comment: if the class had no private members: https://godbolt.org/z/KcxcE9zYz. Note that there is a third case of `student() = default;` afaik all three are different, but the consequences are sublte

Comment: And a fourth case: `class student { int rollNumber{0}; int age = 0;  };`

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a concept of [const-default-constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization#Default_initialization_of_a_const_object) types ([[dcl.init.general]p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#def:const-default-constructible)). It requires that if a const-qualified type `T` is default initialized, it must be const-default-constructible.

For classes, it must have a user-provided constructor, or every member must have a default member initializer or be const-default-constructible itself.

This is why the first example compiles (`student(){}` is user provided), and the second one fails (`int rollNumber;` and `int age;` don't have an initializer).

As for the why, the answer is "the standard says so". The rationale for this is given in [[diff.dcl]p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.iso#diff.dcl-4):

> A const object cannot be assigned to so it must be initialized to hold a useful value.

And it's been that way since C++98.

Though I agree that this seems like too strict of a restriction (What if all the members are mutable? What if you want to read the default member initializer of a single member, leaving the others uninitialized? What if you want to construct a dummy object to pass to something else with everything uninitialized?) In all cases though, you can do something like `student _s; const student& s = _s;` for basically the same effect.

---

This is one of the differences between the compiler provided default constructor and an explicit `student() {}`. A few more are:

- The user provided one isn't trivial nor an aggregate (and this one wouldn't be usable in a constant expression)
- `noexcept`-ness is automatically determined
- The compiler provided one may be `delete`d
- The user provided constructor explicitly will instantiate all the default constructors/member initializers of the members/bases in the body of the class (rather than when you attempt to use it)

And probably some more. These are the differences between user-provided and compiler generated constructors in general, being const-default-constructible seems to be the only one unique to default constructors.

Comment: "_and it wouldn't be constexpr in C++23_": Why only in C++23?

Comment: @user17732522 I was thinking about uninitialized values being allowed in C++23 constexpr evaluation, but I forgot about value initialization (`constexpr student() = default` is an error in C++20, but you can still do `student s{}`)

Comment: The change allowing incomplete initialization in a `constexpr` constructor happened already for C++20. So the implicit default constructor should be `constexpr` already since C++20.

Comment: @user17732522 Ah my mistake. Change those numbers C++23->C++20, C++20->C++17. I've reworded the post to fix it